# println method - what do the last 2 letters (l & n) stand for?

Tags: java, out, println

I guess it's related to `println()`'s newline functionality (`'\n'`), but in abbreviated letter-based form, that would be `nl` rather than `ln`. Thank you for any comments.

Comment: println - print line. Meaning it will use **\n** at  the end of the printed line.

Comment: Its not asking to print new line but it prints the given line with \n at the end.

Comment: println - Print a line(a complete line, which is terminated with a new line character(default line separator) or the line separator property).

Comment: If you got your answer, go ahead and accept it. Please do not add it to your question. It defeats the whole purpose of a Q&A if you're going to include the answer in your question itself. Or else, if you've something new to share with us(which hasn't been posted already), you can post a new answer to your own question also.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's historic.

Pascal had `write` and `writeln`.

`write` would output a string, leaving the cursor at the end of that string.

`writeln` (where `ln` was short for "line") would `write` a whole line of text and move the cursor to the *start of the next line*, typically by automatically appending a `CRLF` or some other OS-dependent control sequence.

Java inherited the abbreviation, but used `print` instead of `write`.

Comment: I'll consider this in my future language. I'll call it `maroun` and `marounln`.

Comment: just an example of bad naming IMHO

Comment: Really? When I learned Java, I first thought, that it is PrintIn() (with the upper case i) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hi check if this is helpful..

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

You can find it under the heading **Class PrintStream**

`ln` simply means LINE - it prints the character/string in a NEW LINE.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why not? He just wanted to know what ln stands for and a link to verify that

Comment: @Aishvarya agree, however I wouldn't post an **answer** but rather a **comment** to answer this question.

Comment: *Hi check if this is helpful.* - This really shouldn't be the first line of an answer, IMHO. It looks like a suggestion at the most.

Comment: What he is saying is convincing, ln stands for Line not New Line, and that why its ln not nl

Comment: @R.J agree with you on that, it's confusing.

Comment: actually it _doesn't_ print it _in_ a new line.  It ensures that the _next_ output will appear on a new line.

Comment: @Tafari Fair enough. Link only answers already on board now. And the last line might be some light yet OP him self proposed that :)

Answer (score 1):

println stands for printline.

There is nothing special about it :P It will print a new line instead of printing it on the same line.

Comment: A source would be welcome. OP asks what it stands for, and it's possible to find other hypothesis, like the fact "ln" looks like "\n".

Comment: Referring to your edit - *It will print a new line instead of printing it on the same line*. Wrong. it'll print the line and end it with a new line character.

Comment: @R.J According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String), it will print the string and then invoke println() meaning it will print a new empty line.

Comment: The order is important here. If nothing is specified, it prints nothing(blank) and terminates it with the new line character.

Comment: @dystroy IMO OP is just overthinking it. Confusing \n with nl or ln. In regards to his question of what "ln" stands for: it stands for line.

Comment: @dystroy the source is history - other languages used `fooln` to mean do `foo` followed by a _move to next line_ operation.

Comment: @Alnitak I know that. What I'm curious about is if historically "ln" stands for "\n" (like `print + \n`) or for an abbreviation of line. But that interesting part of the question is probably off-topic for SO.

Comment: @dystroy no, it doesn't (and AFAIK cannot) stand for `\n` because that's a "C"ism, and Pascal had `writeln` before C existed.

Comment: @Alnitak That's a damn good point there. I had totally forgotten the pascal literals (`#13#10` wasn't it ?).

Answer (score 0):

println() method
Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

```
 public void println() {
     newLine();
 }
```

Also, there are overloaded methods `println(String s)`, `println(Char c)`, `println(Double d)`, `println(Float f)`, `println(Long l)`, `println(int i)`, `println(bool b)`. 
Here is a link which gives all code.
 http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28%29.

Answer (score 0):

println -> print line.

That means that it will print the line you gave it through the parameter, and goes with the cursor to the next line, waiting for another input.